# Making io.BufferedReader from sys.stdin in Python2

Tags: python, bufferedreader, python-2.x

How can I make a BufferedReader object from a standard file object, like sys.stdin or what you get from 'open'?

(Background: I need a peek() method, which the standard file objects fail at having. Any suggestions to solve this issue are also welcome.)

I'd have sort of expected this to work, but it doesn't:

```
>>> import sys  
>>> import io
>>> io.BufferedReader(sys.stdin)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'readable'
```

(This is Python 2.7)

Hah, got it, at least for anything that has a file descriptor.

```
stream = sys.stdin, or open(...), etc.
reader = io.open(stream.fileno(), mode='rb', closefd=False)
```

Comment: What is a `peek()` method? What is it you want, exactly?

Comment: peek() returns the next item in the stream without removing it from the stream. I am writing a parser and want lookahead.

Comment: What input sources are you using that don't have a file descriptor?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I was also looking for the same code for the same reason (using `.peek()`) a while ago. And this works:

```
reader = io.open(sys.stdin.fileno())
```

Comment: There's no `peek` method on the `reader` object from your snippet, in my testing of it with Python 3.11. The returned stream is of the `io.TextIOWrapper` type (which does not have `peek`).