# Using io.BufferedReader on a stream obtained with open()?

Tags: python, io, python-2.7, buffered

I want to use a buffered stream because I want to use a `peek()` method to peek ahead but use my stream with another method that expects a file-like object. (I'd use `seek()` but may have to handle piped-in I/O that doesn't support random access.)

But this test case fails:

AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute '_checkReadable'

```
import sys
import io

srcfile = sys.argv[1]
with open(srcfile, 'rb') as f:
    fbuf = io.BufferedReader(f)
    print fbuf.read(20)
```

What's going on and how do I fix it? I thought BufferedReader was intended to buffer a stream. If so, why does the `open()` function not return something that's compatible with it?

Comment: It's interesting. Although we have same versions (2.7.x), we get slightly different error messages.

Comment: I found it out. There's a comment in io.py as """Method descriptions and default implementations are inherited from the C version however.""" So it's depending on c versions or OS.

Comment: @username: This is not OS-specific. My Python 2.6.7 complains about `_checkReadable` as well, while my 2.7.2 complains about `readable`. I can't find the commit right now, but this was probably changed this somewhere between 2.7.0 and 2.7.2.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Making io.BufferedReader from sys.stdin in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6065173/making-io-bufferedreader-from-sys-stdin-in-python)

Answer (score 25):

By the looks of your `print` statement, you're using Python 2. On that version, a `file` is not a valid argument to the `BufferedReader` constructor:

> Under Python 2.x, this is proposed as an alternative to the built-in `file` object, but in Python 3.x it is the default interface to access files and streams. ([1](http://docs.python.org/library/io.html))

You should use `io.open` instead:

```
>>> f = io.open(".bashrc", "rb")
```

If you do this, there's no need to explicitly wrap it in a `BufferedReader` since that's exactly what `io.open` returns by default:

```
>>> type(f)
<type '_io.BufferedReader'>
```

See [its docs](http://docs.python.org/library/io.html#io.open) for details; there's a `buffering` argument that controls the buffering.

In Python 3, `open` is `io.open` so the two I/O libraries have been merged back into one. It seems that `io` was added to Python 2.6 mostly for forward compatibility.

Comment: there's no need to wrap for opening a file, but what if I use sys.stdin instead?

Comment: @JasonS: then the [hack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6065173/making-io-bufferedreader-from-sys-stdin-in-python) that `username` pointed to is valid. Or `io.open("/dev/stdin")` if your platform has that file (but in either case stay clear of `sys.stdin`).

Answer (score 6):

You can set the amount of buffering in bytes by passing the [`buffering` argument](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#open) to open:

```
import sys

srcfile = sys.argv[1]
with open(srcfile, 'rb', buffering=30) as f:
    print(f.peek(30))
    print(f.read(20))
```

This is a `BufferedReader`:

```
>>> with open("test.txt", 'rb', buffering=30) as f:
...     type(f)
<class '_io.BufferedReader'>
```

Note that, by default, it's buffered to `1` - line buffered.

Comment: sure, that's fine, but eventually I'm going want to buffer around other sources of input that might not be buffered... or is everything just buffered by default? sys.stdin? network streams?

Comment: Well, then you can do what you did and do ``BufferedReader(f)`` - as it's already a ``BufferedReader`` it will work.

Comment: This is the Python 3 solution; in Python 2 the OP should use `io.open`.

Comment: @larsmans Ah, I didn't know this was a 3.x feature, you are correct.

Comment: Correction: this is actually a pretty valid solution also in Python 2, but `open` will return a `file`, not a `BufferedReader` in 2.x, so there's no `peek` method.

Answer (score 1):

In Python2, if you have to use `file` object as returned by `open` (or e.g. provided by some module routines which you cannot modify), you can use file descriptor obtained by `fileno()` for `io.FileIO` constructor, then pass `io.FileIO` object to `io.BufferedReader` constructor.

So, you sample code can be rewritten as follows:

```
import sys
import io

srcfile = sys.argv[1]
with open(srcfile, 'rb') as f:
    fio  = io.FileIO(f.fileno())
    fbuf = io.BufferedReader(fio)
    print fbuf.read(20)
```